# MySQL query - seemingly weird behavior. Does this have to do with float values?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called `sellerparams` with a number of columns, one of them called `probabilityinc`. The type of this column is `float`.

I don't understand why the second query is not working as I expect.

**First query and result**

```
mysql> select id,probabilityinc from temp.sellerparams;
+----+----------------+
| id | probabilityinc |
+----+----------------+
|  1 |            0.3 |
|  2 |            0.3 |
|  3 |            0.3 |
|  4 |            0.4 |
+----+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Second query and result (unexpected?)**

```
mysql> select id from temp.sellerparams where probabilityinc=0.4;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see there is a row with `probabilityinc=0.4`. Why does the second select return empty? Does this have to do with the internal representation of float values? If so, how can I do selections based on a column that is of type float?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your column type to `numeric`. `float` is inaccurate by design. And numbers like 0.4 can vary slightly. That is why comparing to `0.4` can fail if the number is stored as `0.39999999`

You could use `numeric(10,5)`for instance.

See [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: Thanks. That works well. Is there any difference between Decimal(10,5) and Numeric(10,5). The documentaion says that "In MySQL, NUMERIC is implemented as DECIMAL...", so I suppose not. But would be good to know if they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

It might be better to use a more accurate datatype for your column because floats have fairly limited precision. That said, it is good practice to always use a tolerance value when comparing floating point values

```
select id from temp.sellerparams 
where probabilityinc between (0.4 - epsilon) AND (0.4 + epsilon);
```

where epsilon represents your tolerance, say 0.0001